# i think i have found an answer that is wrong. can you verify

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

the function in question is $f(x)=x^2$sin$(\frac{1}{x})$
RHD$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and LHD$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and $f'(x)=2x$sin$(\frac{1}{x})-$cos$(\frac{1}{x})$

at x=0, RHD$=\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\frac{h^2\sin(\frac1h)-0}h=0 $ and LHD$=\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}\frac{h^2\sin(\frac1h)-0}h=0$, and $f'(0)=$undefined

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550547/does-the-existence-of-the-derivative-at-a-point-imply-the-existence-of-the-left) this is what is answered (in short)

**we assume that ${\bf f(0)=0}$** and prove LHD=RHD=$0$ , at $x=0$ $=>$ derivative exists.
 but $ f'(0)$ does not exist $=>$ RHD and $ f'(x)$ are not the same things

i think the above linked answer is wrong, because of what is answered 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965499/value-of-x2-sin-frac1x-at-x-0) (which in short is)

**${\bf f(x)}$ is undefined at $\bf {x=0}$**, so we define a new function, $ \overline{f}(x) = 
\begin{cases} x^{2} \sin \Big( \frac{1}{x} \Big) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\[2mm]
0 & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}
$

now if we differentiate $ \overline{f}(x) $ , we get $ \overline{f}'(x) = 
\begin{cases} 2x \sin \Big( \frac{1}{x} \Big) -\cos \Big( \frac{1}{x} \Big) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\[2mm]
0 & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}
$

from here we can obtain  at x = $0$, RHD$=\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\frac{h^2\sin(\frac1h)-0}h=0 $ is the same as $ \overline{f}'(0)=\frac{d}{dx}0=0 \implies $RHD and $ \overline{f}'(x)$ are the same things

(note:-$ \overline{f}'(0)=\frac{d}{dx}0=0 $ is wrong. the reason is explianed in one of the answers below.)

edit1:- i don't believe that the derivative $f'(x)$ needs to converge.(i may be wrong but, here's a counter example)

take the function $g(x) = 
\begin{cases} x^3/3+2/3 & \text{if } x < 1 \\[2mm]
-2x+3 & \text{if } x = 1\\[2mm]
 2*x-x^2/2-1/2 & \text{if } x > 1
\end{cases}$

$g'(1)=\frac{d}{dx}(-2x+3)=-2$, but $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}g'(x)=1$, in particular $g'(x) $ has a removable discontinuity (which is allowed, i guess)
(note:-$g'(1)=\frac{d}{dx}(-2x+3)=-2$ is wrong, the reason is explained in one of the answers below.)

edit2:- what i am asking for is

1. is it valid to **assume** $f(0)=0$
2. are $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ and $f'(x_0)$ the same things(in edit1, for function g they are not, hence does derivative of g at x=1 exist. if it exists then is it 1 or -2.)

Comment: Your evaluation of derivative $\bar{f} '$ at $0$ is wrong. You can't it like that, rather you need to use limits and then you will get the derivative as $0$.

Comment: i don't understand. if i take the limit then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\overline{f}'(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}2xsin(\frac{1}{x}) -cos(\frac{1}{x}) $ doesnot converge, since $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}cos(\frac{1}{x})$ doesnot converge

Comment: You need to use the definition of derivative like $$\bar{f} '(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$

Comment: took some time to understand my mistake. but have fixed it now. removed the typos too. thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second edit really gets down to the fundamental issues here. That's a good way to ask a question!

### Response to Question 1.

You can **assume** anything you like at any time, but once you make that assumption you are working in a fictional world relative to the problem you were previously working on.

There are valid methods of proof that are able to "discharge" the assumption so that you end up saying something about your original problem, but in the example you started with there is no such resolution.
In the end it says nothing about the function originally defined by 
$f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x).$

A correct way to deal with this, as others have already pointed out, is to recognize that $f$ has no derivative of any kind at $0$, but you can define a **new** function $\bar f$ by **defining** that $\bar f(0) = 0$ and that $\bar f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ when $x\neq 0.$ The new function is called an extension of $f$ because it is the same as $f$ whenever $f$ is defined but it is also defined at one or more additional points.

In the question you linked to, however ([Does the existence of the derivative at a point imply the existence of the left and right derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550547/does-the-existence-of-the-derivative-at-a-point-imply-the-existence-of-the-left)), I think the words "assuming that" are not making an assumption in the mathematical sense.
Instead, I think the writer of that answer was making a guess that the original source of the question (whatever the "notes" that were mentioned in the question came from, probably a lecture or study session)
was actually dealing with the function $\bar f$ as I defined it above,
and not merely a function defined by $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x).$
So "assuming that" in this case really means "guessing that the example you were working on actually said that".

It is possible that this guess was wrong and that the original source of the example never defined $\bar f(0).$ But if that is true, then the original source of the notes made an error and the question did not make sense.
In that case the answer is answering the question that **should** have been asked.

### Response to Question 2.

Yes, $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ and $f'(x_0)$ are the same thing,

That's because **by the definition of the *derivative* $f'$ of a function $f$**,
$$ f'(x_0) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h} . $$

Anything that contradicts this equation is simply wrong.
In particular, in the example where you define
$$g(x) = 
\begin{cases} x^3/3+2/3 & \text{if } x < 1,\\
-2x+3 & \text{if } x = 1,\\
 2x-x^2/2-\frac12 & \text{if } x > 1,
\end{cases}$$
the correct answer to "what is the derivative of $g$ at $1$?" is
$g'(1) = 1 \neq -2.$

(Note that I changed one of your $>$ signs to $<$ since the definition is self-contradictory otherwise.)

It's true that if the domain of a function $h$ is an interval that includes the number $1$ and some other numbers and that if $h = -2x + 3$ everywhere on that interval, then $h'(1) = -2.$

But that's not how the function $g$ is defined.
The function $g$ is set equal to $-2x + 3$ only at one point, and one point is not enough to define a derivative.

This is such a fundamental error to avoid that I'll say it twice.
You cannot take a derivative of a function simply by looking at the expression that defines the function at one point and applying the usual rules of derivatives
(power rule, scalar factor, etc.).
Those rules only work within intervals of positive length.

Since $g$ us also defined (by different expressions) over an interval that includes $1$ and points on both sides of $1,$ the only correct way to evaluate $g'(1)$ is to use the definition of $g$ on the points on both sides of $1.$

When we evaluate
$$ g'(1) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{g(1+h)-g(1)}{h}, $$
we can legitimately observe that for the left-side derivative, all the values we have to deal with (namely $g(1)$ and $g(1+h)$ for $h<0$)
agree with the function $p(x)=x^3/3+2/3$ defined on all real numbers
(for example, $g(1) = 1 = p(1)$), 
so the left-side derivatives of these two functions at $1$ are equal.
Similarly, all the values used in the right-side derivative of $g$ are the same as the values of the function $q(x)=2x-x^2/2-\frac12$ defined for all real numbers, so the right-side derivatives of these two functions at $1$ are equal.
This lets us very quickly evaluate the derivative $g'(1)$ without having to write out two new delta-epsilon proofs.

Answer (score 4):

It's not very clear what you are asking, but here are some facts:

The function $s : \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R},\ s(x) = x^2 \sin\frac1x$ is not defined at $x=0$ so it can not have a derivative there.

The extension $\bar{s} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\ s(0) = 0,\ s(x) = x^2 \sin\frac1x$ has a derivative everywhere.

The limits $\lim_{x\to0+}\bar{s}'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0-}\bar{s}'(x)$ do not exist.

Generally, a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has a derivative at $0$ if and only if both $\lim_{h\to0+} h^{-1}(f(h)-f(0))$ and $\lim_{h\to0-} h^{-1}(f(h)-f(0))$ exist and are equal.

Also generally, if $\lim_{x\to0+} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0-} f'(x)$ both exist and are equal, then $f'(0)$ exists and equals the previous common limit.

Answer (score 1):

A function always involves its domain. In usual practice the function is specified by giving a formula for image under the function. When this is the case the domain is implicitly provided as the set of all numbers for which the image formula makes sense.

Thus for the function $f$ defined by $f(x) =x^2\sin(1/x)$ the domain is $\mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}$. And therefore we can't talk about its continuity and differentiability at $0$. However we can talk about limit of $f$ at $0$ and we have $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$.

Next consider the function $\bar{f} $ which is a continuous extension of the above function $f$ and is given as $$\bar{f} (x) =x^2\sin(1/x),x\neq 0,\bar{f}(0)=0$$ Now we can talk about its continuity and differentiability at $0$. The function is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$. If $x\neq 0$ then we can use usual differentiation rules and formulas to get $$\bar{f} '(x) =2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$$ To evaluate $\bar{f}'(0)$ we need to go to basics and use definition of derivative $$\bar{f} '(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\bar{f}(x)-\bar{f}(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin(1/x)=0$$ Thus it turns out that $\bar{f} $ is differentiable on whole of $\mathbb{R} $.

Further we can observe something very weird here. The derivative $\bar{f}' (0)$ exists but $\lim_{x\to 0}\bar{f}'(x)$ does not exist. Thus the derivative $\bar{f} '$ is discontinuous at $0$. However note that a derivative can't have *simple* discontinuity. Using mean value theorem one can prove

> **Theorem**: Let $f$ be a real valued function defined in a certain neighborhood of $c$. If $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $\lim_{x\to c} f'(x) $ exists then the derivative $f'(c) $ exists and equals $\lim_{x\to c} f'(x) $.

and

> **Theorem**: Let $f$ be a function defined in a certain neighborhood of $c$. If $f'(c), \lim_{x\to c^{-}} f'(x), \lim_{x\to c^{+}} f'(x) $ exist then they are all equal to each other.

Based on this your analysis of the function $g$ is wrong. Fixing a typo your function is defined as $$g(x) = 
\begin{cases} x^3/3+2/3 & \text{if } x < 1 \\[2mm]
-2x+3 =1 & \text{if } x = 1\\[2mm]
 2*x-x^2/2-1/2 & \text{if } x > 1
\end{cases}$$ Here as you rightly observed $\lim_{x\to 1}g'(x)=1$ and $g$ is continuous at $1$ therefore $g'(1)=1$. How you arrived at the wrong evaluation $g'(1)=-2$ is not clear.

Coming to your last few questions, one can't assume anything more than what is specified in the problem. Thus if a definition of $f(0)$ is not given then you have to understand that $f$ is not defined at $0$ and there is no point discussing continuity / differentiability of $f$ at $0$.

By definition we have $$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$ and those two things are same.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim _{x\to 0}cos(\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist, so $f'(x)$ does not converge as $x\to 0$.

Comment: The derivative doesn't need to be continuous

Comment: @NinadMunshi  I don't get your point.  $f'(0)=0$, but it is not the limit of $f'(x)$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: That's exactly my point, your comment doesn't seem to have a purpose related to OP's post since they never ask about that incongruity. I tried my best to be nice and guess a purpose, but it looked fairly out of place.

Comment: my main problem is with the assumption that f(0)=0. i think it should be undefined

Comment: Because of the $x^2$ term $f(0)=0$, since the term $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is bounded.  Similarly $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0} hsin(\frac{1}{h})$ exists.

Comment: you are directly contradicting  answer by jibounet  here-->https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965499/value-of-x2-sin-frac1x-at-x-0

Comment: I am in agreement with jibonnet.  $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ since $|sin(\frac{1}{x})|\le 1$ and the $x^2$ coefficient $\to 0$.  The question whether $f(0)$ is defined is a somewhat philosophical question.  In my view $x^2=0$ makes the fact that $sin (\frac{1}{0})$ is undefined moot, because of the bound. You can't do the same for $f'(x)$ where $f'(0)=0$ but because of the $cos(\frac{1}{x})$ term, $f'(x)$ has no limit for $x\to 0$.

Comment: No, f(x), as given in the first post, is NOT continuous at x= 0 because it is not defined there.  It is true that the limit, as x goes to 0, exists and is 0.  **IF** f(0) were defined to be 0, then the function would be continuous at x= 0.  But it is not.